# Que pensar ante una pregunta eliminada sin motivo tras una respuesta que te ha llevado su tiempo

Tags: discusión, convenciones-sociales, eliminación-de-preguntas, eliminación-de-respuestas

No es la primera vez que me ocurre y supongo que no será la última, pero la situación llega a ser algo frustrante, pues una respuesta por sencilla que sea lleva su tiempo elaborarla, y que después de realizarla, la persona que hizo la pregunta, sin motivo aparente, la elimine, te deja un poco fuera de sitio.

Y ya no se trata ni de votos ni de reputación, más bien creo que sería de mínimo agradecimiento hacia quien se haya esforzado en dar una respuesta a las dudas que se puedan plantear.

Y de ahí mi duda, que puede pasar por la cabeza de la gente que pregunta y una vez obtiene una respuesta, elimina su pregunta, quedándose con la respuesta supongo.

Es como pensar que mi duda es mía y nadie en éste mundo podrá tener la misma, así que como no resultará de interés para nadie más, la elimino.

Bueno, que quizás no sea el sitio adecuado para plantear el tema de mi frustración y que si me estoy equivocando al ponerlo, os pido disculpas por ello.

Un saludo

Comment: Es el sitio adecuado y entiendo tu frustración. En el [centro de ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question) se explica los problemas de eliminar una pregunta, pero aun asi el autor puede eliminarla. Eso si, hay ciertos requisitos que pueden impedir este borrado: si la pregunta tiene respuestas con votos positivos, el autor no podrá eliminarla. Tambien decirte que si se insiste en esto, el sistema puede llegar a bloquear al usuario para realizar preguntas.

Comment: Gracias por el comentario @Pikoh, pero tampoco deseo ese bloqueo ni penalización alguna. Simplemente deseaba comentar un hecho que me parece un poco injusto, porque como comentaba, una respuesta puede llevar entre treinta segundos o varias horas dependiendo de la dificultad de la misma. Y que después de elaborarla y publicarla, que sin motivo, el que la haya formulado la elimine, me parececía eso, una injusticia. Creo que una vez se haya efectuado una pregunta y tenga respuesta, antes de su eliminación el que haya respondido debería de tener que aprobar dicha eliminación.

Comment: Es muy frustrante sin duda, pero si consideras que tu respuesta es valiosa para otros, puedes escribir la pregunta siguiendo lo lineamientos de [ask] y autoresponderla.

Comment: Creo que lo más frustrante es que parecería haber usuarios en el sitio que pierden de vista la idea, que es ayudar no solo a quien pregunta, sino a toda una comunidad. Soy súper nuevo, y ni siquiera soy programador (aunque si que tengo intenciones de serlo), pero aún así trato de ayudar con lo que sé, y me he chocado (un poco) con actitudes que no son presisamente las de pensar en el bien común.

Comment: Si no esperas nada de los demás, nunca sufrirás decepciones.

Comment: Me ha sucedido en varias ocasiones, regularmente es con usuarios nuevos, las causas que conozco por el usuario son : - Resolvió su problema que era ortográfico. - Resolvió un problema que solo el podía reproducir. - Resolvió su problema en base a tu respuesta y por desconocimiento del funcionamiento del sitio simplemente eliminó su pregunta.  No desesperes, evita también responder preguntas que carezcan de información o sean malas, hay que sugerir mejorar sus preguntas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Esta situación tiene una solución relativamente sencilla: si consideras que la pregunta borrada y la respuesta son interesantes, crea una pregunta similar y respóndela.

Más de una vez nos hemos encontrado malas preguntas o preguntas donde el que *el OP* no es plenamente consciente del problema (por falta de experiencia) y eso hace que tanto la pregunta como la respuesta no vayan a tener la visibilidad que permitiría ayudar a otras personas. Otra veces la pregunta es borrada porque *el OP* así lo ha querido

Varios usuarios hemos optado por crear lo que llamamos una **pregunta + respuesta canónicas**: Una pregunta donde se presenta un escenario muy definido y aislado que se presenta a menudo, seguida de una respuesta que a la vez intenta ser genérica y práctica: explicamos con detalle cuál es el problema y cómo solucionarlo o evitarlo.
Cualquier pregunta posterior que se puede reducir a estos escenarios es a menudo cerrada como duplicada de una de estas preguntas, lo que hace que estas preguntas + respuestas ganen con el tiempo votos y visibilidad.

Ejemplos:

- [¿Cómo comparar correctamente Strings (y objetos) en Java?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/225/c%c3%b3mo-comparar-correctamente-strings-y-objetos-en-java)
- [¿Qué es la inyección SQL y cómo puedo evitarla?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/10518/qu%c3%a9-es-la-inyecci%c3%b3n-sql-y-c%c3%b3mo-puedo-evitarla)
- [¿Cuál es la solución a todos los errores NullPointerException presentes, pasados y futuros?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/42977/cu%c3%a1l-es-la-soluci%c3%b3n-a-todos-los-errores-nullpointerexception-presentes-pasados)
- [Cómo separar un String en Java. Cómo utilizar split()](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/45846/c%c3%b3mo-separar-un-string-en-java-c%c3%b3mo-utilizar-split)
- [¿Cuál es la diferencia entre JSON y un objeto?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/164943/cu%c3%a1l-es-la-diferencia-entre-json-y-un-objeto)